# Rebinding Numpad . (location 104) to regular dot (location 54)

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, windows-registry

How can I remap the numeric dot (key location 104) to regular dot (key location 54) in Windows 7? The key should always behave as a dot, regardless of the state of NumLock key. I'm using the standard 101/102 keyboard.

I'd like to do this without using any third party applications, or changing the Regional settings in Windows 7.

I know that I can (theoretically) get it done by changing the scancode map in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout\Scancode Map
```

but I'm unsure on how to go about it. I'm thinking that this

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,34,e0,??,??,\
00,00,00,00
```

isn't that far off, I just need to know what to put in place of question marks. I've consulted Microsoft's [Keyboard scancode specificaton](https://www.google.com/search?q=keyboard%20scancode%20specification) manual, and the value for the Numeric dot is 53, but I'm unsure if I could pair it with e0 (due to undefined NumLock state).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, I was indeed close. NumLock state had nothing to do with it. I'd decided to go ahead with rebinding NumPad dot - 00_53 (inverse hex 53 00) to ordinary dot - 00_34 (inverse hex 34 00), and it works as I'd hoped it would. NumPad dot is always a dot, regardless of the regional settings.

This was achieved by creating a registry binary key called `Scancode Map` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout`.

The next step was to modify its data, which I did by typing this:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
02 00 00 00 34 00 53 00
00 00 00 00
```

After rebooting, the NumPad dot acted as an ordinary dot.