# Make numpad comma key type dot instead of comma through registry

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, numpad

I know there is registry hack what make numpad comma key write dot instead of comma. I used this hack back on XP but I'm unable to find it on 7.It is because I'm developer and floats uses dot as separator, comma already given me many syntax errors. I'm using lenovo laptop B50-80.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind. I found meintoned registry hack. When I was looking for it I did not used keyworld "rebind" so I did not found it. 
[Rebinding Numpad . (location 104) to regular dot (location 54)](https://superuser.com/questions/1173975/rebinding-numpad-location-104-to-regular-dot-location-54?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably directly related to the country you specify as keyboard default. Some European countries use the comma as the decimal separator, the rest of the world doesn't.

Try Control Panels > Region & Language > Additional settings... > Decimal symbol

[image]

Comment: No. I have set it but it won't affect keypad comma key.

Comment: ah, OK - I couldn't test as mine doesn't have a comma there, it does have a period.

Comment: That is alright @Tessujin. I tried to look for registry key myself but there are way too much keys, maybe around 20 000 of keys or more. It may take ages to find right one besides fact it may have nonsense name.